# why linux reuse 'time_wait' port?

Tags: linux, socket

As I know, tcp port in 'time_wait' stat cann't be used. However, in my experiment, server reuses the 'time_wait' port? Why?

Firstly, in client machine, type command `ehco 40000 40001 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`. So, the maximum number of TCP ports is 2.

**server code**

```
while (1) {
    int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    fd = accept(sfd, &remote, &len);

    read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    close(fd);
}
```

**client code**

```
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        sleep(1);
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            handler();
            exit(0);
        }
    }

 void handler()
 {
      * ............. */

      res = connect(sfd, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
      if (res == -1) {
        perror("error");
        exit(1);
      }

      printf("connect\n");
 }
```

**show**

```
[root@livecd ~]# ./client 
connect
[root@livecd ~]# connect
connect
```

It's up to 3 connections. I think, 2 connections at most. Why ?
 server has 2 timewait connections.

```
[root@livecd ~]# netstat -anp | grep TIME
tcp  192.168.88.131:2016   192.168.88.132:40000  TIME_WAIT                  
tcp  192.168.88.131:2016   192.168.88.132:40001  TIME_WAIT
```

**Environment**

```
Linux livecd.centos 2.6.32-642.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue May 10 16:13:51 UTC 2016
```

**server config**

```
[root@livecd ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout 
60
[root@livecd ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle 
0
[root@livecd ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse 
0
```

**client config**

```
[root@livecd ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range 
40000   40001
```

**Important**
    I also try ubuntu server 14.04, but got the same result.

Comment: Is the client really always using the same port?  That shouldn't happen unless you forced it to somehow, each `connect` call should use a different port on the client, but your `netstat` output looks like the port number at the client got reused.  In fact that `netstat` output seems like it's impossible.  I think you edited the transcript and added bogons.

Comment: Client uses two ports 40000, 40001. It really happened in my expriment. I don't why ?

Comment: Your netstat shows the other port as 2016 both times.

Comment: Port 2016 is the server's listening port.

Comment: Can you post the whole code for the server and client somewhere? e.g. pastebin or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be lots of errors in the transcribed parts of the question, and important bits are missing, but I think I can answer any way.  The fact that there are only two port numbers, does **not** mean there can only be two connections.  Connections are distinguished by the four values:

- source address
- source port
- destination address
- destination port

So, if as is normal, the client opens the new connections with a new port number on its end, the same port number can be used by the server and they are still distinct TCP connections.  This is the way *most* servers work, there is only **one** port at the server end (the so-called "well known port" for the service) that the server listens on, and each client that connects to it has a different local address + port on the client.

So, you really should see three connections.  Probably the reason you only see two is that one has already waited the appropriate time, or one has not yet gotten to that state.  Your grep filter is probably hiding vital information.  For this test you might want to have the server print something locally as it accepts each connection.

Comment: Client can open new connctions with only two ports(40000, 40001). I think if two ports stats are in `TIME_OUT`, client should not open new connections.

Comment: OK, despite a couple of people upvoting my answer here, it's *not* the answer to the original question.  I got confused by all the transcription errors and missed the point that the port restriction was on the client.  In that case, I think he's right, there should have been an error when the client tried to open a third connection.  The first two would not have timed out yet and there's no unique 4-tuple for the third connection.  Getting an actual answer to what's happening probably requires delving into kernel sources and RFCs.

Comment: If the connection is in the **TIME_WAIT** state and new connction's sequence number is greater than the final sequence number for the connection, then new connection can be created. See <TCP/IP illustrated Volume2> Page 986.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  The sequence number, while not part of the connection identification can (and sometimes is) used to recycle an old 4-tuple, if there's no other option.